# Printing stack trace including methods that have finished

Tags: java, stack-trace, throwable, printstacktrace

So, I have this class and I want to print which methods were called. When I run it it prints only trace and main but not method1 and method2. How can I change it so it would print method1 and method2, the methods called from main?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void method1() {}
    public void method2() {}

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Throwable 
    {
        SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
        c.method1();
        c.method2();
        SomeClass.trace();
    }

    public static void trace() throws Throwable
    {
        Throwable t = new Throwable();
        StackTraceElement[] stack = t.getStackTrace();
        for(StackTraceElement s : stack)
        System.out.println(s.getMethodName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`method1` and `method2` have been called but have *completed* their work, so there's no reason for them to be in the trace. A stack trace's job is to show you what functions are *in progress* (what calls are outstanding on the stack).

If you're looking for something that will tell you they *were* called (but have finished), the category of tool you're looking for is called a "code coverage" testing tool. That's not part of what the exception and stack trace aspects of the Java runtime are for.

Comment: That explains it then. Thank you for your quick answer.